# QGIS 2.16.2 Windows 10 installation error: ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, installation, qgis-2, dll

I have just installed QGIS 2.16.2 from binaries. But it can't load QGIS utilis because of this problem:

```
Couldn't load QGIS utils.
Python support will be disabled.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 21, in 
    standard_library.install_aliases()
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\standard_library\__init__.py", line 457, in install_aliases
    __import__(oldmodname)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\backports\__init__.py", line 17, in 
    from .misc import (ceil,
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.16\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\future\backports\misc.py", line 24, in 
    from socket import getaddrinfo, SOCK_STREAM, error, socket
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 47, in 
    import _socket
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.


 Python Version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

QGIS Version:
2.16.2 'Nødebo', 979e1a2

Python path:
['C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/OPdaTe/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/OPdaTe/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.16/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Users\\OPdaTe\\Documents\\Python Script', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Program Files\\FreeCAD 0.16\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGIS2~1.16\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg']
```

Any idea how to fix it? I have already unistalled it and install it twice.

Comment: You're running 32-bit Python?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/5286203/2258

Comment: @RichardMorgan in my console I see 32bit python